# What theorem said that $L^2[a,b]$ is dense in $L^1[a,b]$ in Royden "Real analysis " 4th edition.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, lebesgue-integral

I was reading the solution of this question:

[Show that $L^2[a,b]$ is of the first category](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2703929/show-that-l2a-b-is-of-the-first-category)

But I do not know: What theorem said that  $L^2[a,b]$ is dense in $L^1[a,b]$ in Royden "Real analysis " 4th edition. Could anyone help me in finding this theorem ?

Also, could anyone tell me the general idea of the solution given in this link please?

Comment: The proof of that statement is described in the answer you linked. For $f\in L^1[a,b]$ check that $f\cdot \Bbb1_{|f|^{-1}([0,n]}$ is in $L^2$ and that this converges to $f$ in $L^1$ sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f \in L^{1}[a,b]$ then $f_n =fI_{\{|f| \leq n}\}$ is  sequence in $L^{2}[a,b]$ converging in $L^{1}[a,b]$  to $f$.

Comment: Why we are sure of the existence of this sequence $f_{n}$ and why we are sure that it is in $L^2$?

Comment: @Mathstupid $\int|f_n|^{2} \leq n\int |f|$ so $f_n \in L^{2}$ for each $n$. $f_n \to f$ in $L^{1}$ by DCT.

Comment: Do we have to use the open mapping theorem in the proof?

Comment: Doesn't this also show the stronger fact that $L^\infty([a,b])$ is dense in $L^1([a,b])$

Comment: Yes it does indeed.