# Why we take $U := \{ f \in L^2[a,b]: \|f\|_{L^2[a,b]} \leq 1 \}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

I was reading this question:

[Show that $L^2[a,b]$ is of the first category](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2703929/show-that-l2a-b-is-of-the-first-category)

But I did not understand why the answer took $U := \{ f \in L^2[a,b]: \|f\|_{L^2[a,b]} \leq 1 \}$? could anyone explain this for me please?

Especially because in this link:

[$L^2([0,1])$ is a set of first category in $L^1([0,1])$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140096/l20-1-is-a-set-of-first-category-in-l10-1/140098#140098)

I saw a different set $B_{n}.$

Comment: The $B_n$ in the second post is the same as the $nU$ in the first post.

Comment: And why we want $U$ to take this form @Thorgott specifically?

Comment: The fundamental reason is that it accomplishes what we want it to accomplish. If you're asking for motivation for that choice of $U$, I'm afraid I can't help you, but then you should probably make that more explicit.

Comment: Yes I am asking about the intuition behind writing it write this @Thorgott